# Laravel Complex Relationships Through Polymorphism

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models using Laravel 5.3:

Provider:

```
// Provider model

$primaryKey = 'id'

public function activities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
}
```

Activity:

```
// Activity model

$primaryKey = 'id'

public function provider()
{
    return $this-belongsTo(Provider::class);
}

public function semesters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Semester::class);
}

public function semesterPurchases()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Purchase::class, Semester::class, 'activity_id', 'purchasable_id')
        ->where('purchasable_type', Semester::class);
}
```

Semester:

```
// Semester model

$primaryKey = 'id'

public function activity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Activity::class, 'activity_id', 'id');
}
```

Purchase:

```
// Purchase model

$primaryKey = 'id'

public function purchasable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In my case `Semester::class` is the `purchasable_type`. Is there a way to establish a relationship between `Provider::class` and `Purchase::class`? In order to make it possible to do something like this:

```
$providers = Provider::select('id', 'name', 'address')
  ->with('purchases')
  ->where('providers.id', 1)
  ->get();
```

I would prefer not to go through activities like so:

```
$providers = Provider::select('id', 'name', 'address')
  ->with('activities.purchases')
  ->where('providers.id', 1)
  ->get();
```

which I know I can do using `hasManyThrough` on the `Activity::class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```php
class Provider extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Purchase::class,
            [Activity::class, Semester::class],
            [null, null, ['purchasable_type', 'purchasable_id']]
        );
    }
}

Provider::find($id)->purchases;
```